# Java script - how to end connection to DB?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a code bellow and it is running fine (getting data from database) but when I run it from a terminal (e.g. `node db.js`) - it gives data back but never closes (can not type next command in terminal.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: '...',
    user: '...',
    password: "...,
    port : ..., //port mysql
    database: '...'
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  connection.query("SELECT * FROM table", function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
  });
});
```

What should be added to the end of `.js` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can end connections with `connection.end();`
You must add it after the query because the query must be completed first. Here is your modified code:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: '...',
    user: '...',
    password: "...,
    port : ..., //port mysql
    database: '...'
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  connection.query("SELECT * FROM table", function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
  });
  connection.end();
});
```

> Closing the connection is done using end() which makes sure all
>   remaining queries are executed before sending a quit packet to the
>   mysql server.

https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#introduction

Answer (score 0):

because all the queries must complete before ending a connection put the following line outside the callback:

connection.end();

Answer (score 0):

You can end the process by calling the 
`process.exit();` method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell MySQL.js to close the connection, once you're done with the query. For example:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: '...',
    user: '...',
    password: "...,
    port : ..., //port mysql
    database: '...'
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  connection.query("SELECT * FROM table", function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
    connection.end(function (err) { if (err) throw err; } });
  });
});
```

For more info, see MySQL.js docs: https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#terminating-connections

Comment: Also, opening and closing the connection each time you need to interact with the database is extremely inefficient. I'd look in the docs and read up on connection pooling, which is a good way to manage MySQL connections in your app.